# obtaining full system environment paths in java

Tags: java

I use System.getenv() to obtain the value of a system env. variable in Windows and get back something of the form:

C:\PROGRA~1...

ie; the short form.

Is it possible to obtain the full form; eg "C:\PROGRAM FILES..."

I want to perform a search on the returned string and would be better if I was working with the full string.

Thanks

Graham

Answer (score 1):

No and yes.

No you can't get them in that form from the "env" property object / map.

But you should be able to translate those DOS-style "8.3" filenames to full filenames.

<strike>Apparently, it is as simple as calling `File.getCanonicalPath()` on the path containing "8.3" names ... if you are running on Windows.</strike>  ... Or so I read somewhere.  Apparently that's not correct.

The standard "Microsoft" way to do this is to use `Win32::GetLongPathName(PATHNAME)` from the Win32 std library.  I couldn't find *anything* in Java that does this, so you may need to resort to JNI / JNA.

The other alternative is to stomp on whatever is putting 8.3 paths into the Windows environment variables.

Comment: Just looking at the javadoc of File.getCanonicalPath() which states "The precise definition of canonical form is system-dependent.". Testing it I still get the short names.